# Linking between Jira issues in different projects

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

Does the JIRA SOAP API allow me to link betwen two issues that are in different projects? I have looked online and not found a way to do this. The closest thing that I have seen is the createIssueWithParent method, which creates subissues (I want two issues to be linked, not subissues) and which requires the issues to be in the same project (also not what I want).

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I finally got this working using REST, but I can only create issue links that are of the type "Duplicate". I want to create "is related to" links, but setting my type to various things like "is related to" and "relates to" don't work. Does anyone know the linkTypes that are valid?

Comment: It turns out that "Related" is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No easy way in SOAP but I've done this using the RESTful approach and JIRA 4.4, e.g.

```
#
# Add links to JIRA issues
#
# Matt Doar
# CustomWare
# 
# usage: create_links.sh issue_id issue_key
# where the issue_id is the unique id for a JIRA issue, not it's issue key.
# You can see the issue id in the XML view of an issue.
# and issue_key is the other issue to be linked to.

USERNAME=admin
PASSWORD=secret
SERVER_URL="http://localhost:8080"

DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL=$SERVER_URL/secure/Dashboard.jspa
COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION=jiracoookie

# Get the authentication cookie
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD --cookie-jar $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION -sS --output /dev/null $DASHBOARD_PAGE_URL

issueid=$1
issuekey=$2
#echo "Linking issue: $issueid and $issuekey"
curl --cookie $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION --header "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -sS --output /dev/null -d "id=$issueid" -d "linkDesc=relates to" -d "linkKey=$issuekey" "$SERVER_URL/secure/LinkExistingIssue.jspa"

rm -f $COOKIE_FILE_LOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

[I don't think that linking is possible](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/68925/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-link-jira-4-2-issues#comment-68997) via the SOAP API. I've done this using the [XML-RPC API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview), with the [`createIssueLink`](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/5.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/link/IssueLinkManager.html#createIssueLink%28java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long,%20com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User%29) function:

```
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager
# get issue objects
authenticationContext = ComponentManager.getInstance().getJiraAuthenticationContext()
issueLinkManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueLinkManager()
# Link parent issue to subtask
issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issue.getId(),otherIssue.getId(),10003,1,authenticationContext.getUser())
```